# $('#searchfield').keyup(function(e){

Tags: jquery, onkeyup

i have a little question.
Is it possible to call the keyup function with an extra value?

For example

```
$('#eld').keyup(function test(e,val2){
    test('','hallo');
```

But this will not work. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should explain what do you want to achieve. Your question is very vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is, pass `custom data` through the [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method of jQuery.

For instance.

```
$('#eld').keyup(function(e, val2){
  alert(val2);
});
```

Now you can trigger the `keyup` with

```
$('#somebutton').click(function(){
    $('#eld').trigger('keyup', ['custom data']);
});
```

You can pass an array of `custom data` through `.trigger()` as second parameter.

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/

Comment: Ow thats nasty. Just don't push enter to close the alert ;)